# I've made a design in Quartus-II (modelsim), now I want to pass it to the board (I request ORIENTATION)?

Tags: verilog, fpga, synthesis, quartus

once again I request your orientation.

I have successfully designed a circuit in verilog trough Quartus-II and Modelsim,

Details:

Basically it's a (kinda complex) arithmetic circuit based on binary fixed point arithmetic using a FSM (in order to generate the less hardware possible, I made it access only 1 module for division and 1 for multiplication, supposedly this should save area).

Data input comes from a **.txt file** I wrote with a string of 32 bits binary numbers, in total 57.600 of them. I use the command $readmemb to read that file into a **memory arrangement** like this:

```
reg [31:0] in_ram [0:57599];
```

then with a signal (initially with Zero) read each number and process it (then triggering the next one). Result is also loaded into a **memory arrangement** with the result of the calculation of each number through the equation).

Until now everything run perfects, arithmetically results are correct, data is loaded from and to this "memory arrangements". In the Testbench I use commands $fopen and $fdisplay, to open and write respectively a new .txt file with the results.

My next step:

. **NOW I want to pass this design to my DE1-SOC Altera FPGA and measure resulting values of **Area, Speed and Energy**.**

I don't have idea where to start, what should I do now, because I guess testbenchs don't pass to the FPGA, it is not "synthesizable". Speculating, I should somehow load this data **into** the FPGA and then make the results accessible **from** the FPGA and somehow readable to an user.

Conditions for my work are pretty flexible, **I want to use the faster simpler way to do it**. Data doesn't change frequently, it's a pre-established data with a pre-expected result. Also I don't have frecuency, speed constraints directly established, but it should run the standard constraints (this is one of the parts I ignore at all).

I appreciate your opinions. Thank you.

PD: what about this? :

> Another possibility, much less resource demanding, is to use the
>   built-in devices in your FPGA board to send the 1000 byte array
>   through a serial port or USB, receive it in your PC and save to disk
>   from there.

source:
[i want a synthesizable code to save the output in a file in verilog,,,,in vertex 6 kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178523/i-want-a-synthesizable-code-to-save-the-output-in-a-file-in-verilog-in-vertex)

Comment: The DE1 SOC uses the Altera 5CSEMA5F31C6  device, which has 4450 kbits of embedded memory. Your requirement is almost 230 kbits, so if you are not using the embedded RAMs in your fixed point arithmetic circuit, you can use the embedded memory to store your data.

Answer (score -1):

this looks like a big question. Here's my attemp to answer it by explaning what I would do if I were you :

Prashant has a good point about memory usage. Since you are not updating your base data often you can store it in your design instead of using the processor of your SOC for this.

That being said, you will need the processor of your SOC to make your data accessible for a user. To do so, you could use **Altera QSYS** which provide IPs to program your HPS (hard processor on your chip). Those IPs include link to your FPGA design with which you will be able to communicate data between your logic and the HPS itself.

From the QSYS project, you can generate HDL to include in your code, this HDL is the HPS module.

Once this is integrated in your code, you can generate your bit file (.rbf) which can be uploaded to your development board.

The last step is to program the HPS (installing a basic linux distribution) in order to access this data.

The hard part is getting your data out for a user, there are many ways to do it. This is one and might not be the easiest one, but it only uses your board ressources and once you have a QSYS project you can reuse it on your dev board for other FPGA projects.

Hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: What if I only want to be "able" to read the results on the synthesized memory, I'm not looking for a user to see the results, but as a designer level I want to check the results are correct. Do I still need to use the Nios-II and Qsys?